# How i can fix network adapter issue on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, realtek, iwlwifi

im unable to connect either by wifi or lan to internet
how i can fix this my wifi is product : Wi-Fi 6 AX201

LAN product : Realtek Semiconductor

Comment: Wired and wireless issues are different issues. Most likely they are unrelated to each other unless you have some other problem with an internet connection.

Comment: yes i know i just need any solution for any of them, then i can update the driver 
but now im unable to see either wifi settings or wired settings

Comment: I cannot find it on this [website](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers). It's probably not supported (yet).

Comment: Please choose what are you asking about wired or a wireless problem and update your question. Then it will be possible to suggest a solution.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend to use Kernel 5.7.4 or higher for using the Intel AX200, older kernel versions don't seem to work well but with that version this network card works decently well, at least on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
sudo su
cd /tmp/
```

wget -c [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.3/amd64/linux-headers-5.8.3-050803-generic_5.8.3-050803.202008211236_amd64.deb](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.3/amd64/linux-headers-5.8.3-050803-generic_5.8.3-050803.202008211236_amd64.deb)

wget -c [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.3/amd64/linux-headers-5.8.3-050803_5.8.3-050803.202008211236_all.deb](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.3/amd64/linux-headers-5.8.3-050803_5.8.3-050803.202008211236_all.deb)

wget -c [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.3/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.8.3-050803-generic_5.8.3-050803.202008211236_amd64.deb](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.3/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.8.3-050803-generic_5.8.3-050803.202008211236_amd64.deb)

wget -c [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.3/amd64/linux-modules-5.8.3-050803-generic_5.8.3-050803.202008211236_amd64.deb](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.3/amd64/linux-modules-5.8.3-050803-generic_5.8.3-050803.202008211236_amd64.deb)

dpkg -i *.deb

Uninstall Linux Kernel 5.8:

Restart your machine and select boot with the previous kernel in boot menu ‘Grub2 -> Advanced Option for Ubuntu’. Then run command to remove Linux Kernel 5.8:

sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-unsigned-5.8.3-050803-generic_5.8.3-050803.202008211236_amd64.deb
or
sudo apt purge linux-image-unsigned-5.8.3-050803-generic_5.8.3-050803.202008211236_amd64.deb

Comment: Huh? You recommend a 5.7.4 kernel, wget a 5.8.3 kernel, then uninstall a 5.8 kernel. Can't wget on a system with no lan/wi-fi connectivity.

Comment: Well you write comments from some device?